# Magento not finding theme in local instance after MYSQL import

Tags: magento-1.9, theme, theme-fallback

I have a local & remote Magento instances that are branches on the same repo. I exported the remote MYSQL  database (which has all the products and settings I need) and imported it into the local instance. After that, I followed all the necessary things to make it operate properly. Everything is working, but somehow the local instance isn't finding my theme, and it is falling back to the "base" default theme appears on the home page.

Since the file structure and databases are the same, and everything but the theme is working, I'm having trouble working out why the theme would appear on the remote instance and not on the local instance.

Here is a list of things I did to make the local instance work after importing to make it work (This should help rule out some factors):

- Changed the base [url](https://kb.magenting.com/content/5/9/en/change-magento-base-url.html)
- Deleted `/var/cache/` & `/var/session/`
- In System > Configuration > General > Design, set Current Package name to "mytheme" & Templates to "default" (for Default Config. This follows the file structure. Same structure works on remote instance.)

Some other thing to take into consideration:

- The is that the remote server has two stores, one at `store.site.com` and another at `themedev.store.site.com`. Due to the issues, on the local instance, I deleted the `themedev` store and have the default store pointing to `http://themedev:8888/`, which I set up using Mamp Pro. In System > Configuration > General > Web for the Base URL. (I tried changing the scope to Main Website & and Default Store View, but it had no effect.)
- System > Configuration > Developer > CSS Settings > Merge CSS Files is set to "No" (JavaScript Settings also).
- System > Design is empty.

So, I feel like I've exhausted the possibilities of what could be causing the issue.

Any idea what might be causing this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Sequel Pro you might have run into an issue that causes Sequel Pro to improperly import Magento Databases due to a `Primary Key Constraint` since Community 1.8 & Enterprise 1.13. Everything will seem like it imported somewhat properly, but in the end you'll be missing data from tables such as `core_store`.  If this is the case, I would suggest using mysql command line to import your database from now on.

`mysql -uYOUR_USERNAME -p DATABASE_YOUR_IMPORTING_TO < PATH/TO/SEQUEL/FILE.sql`

You should then be prompted for your MySQL password, enter it and eventually you should have a DB imported without missing data from `core_store`, which then will hopefully clear up your theme assignment issues.